# TileMapRenderer in libGDX not drawing anything

Tags: java, tiles, libgdx

So I followed the [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsTileMaps) on the libGDX wiki to draw Tiled maps but it doesn't seem to render anything.

Here's how I setup my `OrthographicCamera` and load the map:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

map = TiledLoader.createMap(Gdx.files.internal("maps/test.tmx"));
atlas = new TileAtlas(map, Gdx.files.internal("maps"));
tileMapRenderer = new TileMapRenderer(map, atlas, 8, 8);
```

And here is my render function:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

camera.update();
tileMapRenderer.render(camera);
```

Also I did pack the tile map using the `TiledMapPacker`.

I'm completely stumped... am I missing anything obvious here?

**EDIT:**

While debugging I noticed that the `TileAtlas` seems to be empty, which I guess shouldn't be the case, but I have no idea why it's empty.

Comment: Hello, I can't help you with it, but I'll leave you with a working sample so you can work from there in case you have not seem it already... [Sample Link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/TiledMapTest.java) . Also, the resources used: [Resources used](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/tiledmap/flip_rotate)

Comment: Thanks. The example doesn't work for me either... even with the resources you linked to. So either the renderer is broken in the latest release or there's something wrong with my system...

Comment: I just tried it here, and is working. Did you got any error while trying to run the project? (Ps.: I'm using the tmx map I linked above)

Comment: Unfortunately not... Just a black screen with red text.

Comment: Okay i found out what the problem was... I feel really stupid now :) Apparently when using the standard libgdx project structure in eclipse you have to refresh the android project before the base project can access the resources... still strange that i didn't get any errors though...

Comment: Oh yeah, it does that. Sometimes, if you don't do "F5" in the Android Project, it will not package a new .APK file, and will just start the old activity :(